# WSPBuilder for vs 2012

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013, wspbuilder

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I am using trial version vs 2012. I want to use the WSPBuilder to develop the web parts. I have install the WSPBuilder and it is not showing in vs 2012.

I have used the below link but not solved the issue.

http://gblsharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/01/using-wspbuilder-with-visual-studio-2012.htm

I have done the copy and past the "Microsoft Visual Studio" and "Microsoft Visual Studio Macros" hot applications and given the version as "11.0". It is working.

Can any one help me

Comment: I used to use WSP builder but i find that VS 2012 is way better at creating packages and wsp's. THe only thing that i would do is get the fishbone toolset to help doing iisresets and copying to the hive.

Answer (score 3):

WSP Builder had it's use back in the SharePoint 2007 days, where Visual Studio had no support for SharePoint packages.

Ever since the release of Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 there is no real need for WSP Builder anymore.

In order to use Visual Studio 2012 with SharePoint 2013 you will have to install an additional package though. To install it, launch the Web Platform Installer (or download the installer if it's not on your server from http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). In the installer, search for SharePoint. From the results, install Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012.

Launch Visual Studio and when you create a new project/solution you should see a Office/SharePoint category. Underneath there, pick the SharePoint Solutions category. If you just want to create a single webpart in a WSP file, then the easiest is to pick the "SharePoint 2013 - Visual Web Part" project item. That will set you with a project containing a feature, a visual webpart that you can extend with your own code, etc. Build the webpart and you will end up with a WSP file in your debug/release folders that you can deploy to your server (or by simply pressing F5 it will automatically deploy it to the farm / site you specified when creating the project).

If you use F5 to deploy, don't forget to add the webpart to a page after deployment as Visual Studio will not do that for you (Edit a page, switch to the insert tab in the ribbon, pick your webpart. Your webpart will be under the 'custom' category if you don't modify the elements.xml file of the webpart).